# How to resolve strange jquery function behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have two buttons in a line of a datatable and each one of them has his own function on click event.
The problem that the second function won't work when I click on its button but it does when I click on the fist one

Here is the full controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var table
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('wfCtrl', wfCtrl);

    function wfCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/Spring4/data/lworkflows'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var wfs = response.data;

        table = $('#example1').DataTable({
                "data": wfs,

                "columns": [{
                        "className": 'details-control',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "data": "",
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    }, {
                        "data": "code"
                    }, {
                        "data": "statut"
                    }, {
                        "data": "label"
                    }, {
                        "data": "langue"
                    }, {
                        "data": "description"
                    }, {
                        "orderable": false,
                        "defaultContent": "<div class='btn-group'>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success addst-btn' title='add a step' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-addst'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></button>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='edit workflow'></i></button>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' title='delete workflow'><i class='fa fa-trash' ></i></button>" +
                        "</div>"
                    }
                ],
                "order": [[1, "asc"]]
            });

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("error");
    });

    function format(d) {
        $scope.modal = d;

        if (d.length == 0) {
            return "No steps"

        }
        var row = ""
            for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {

                row += "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + d[i].ordre + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + d[i].label + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + d[i].type + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + d[i].mode + "</td>" +
                "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-xs  btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-default" + d[i].ordre + "'>Jump list</button></td>" +
                "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-default'>Consequence list</button></td>" +
                "</tr>"
            }

            return "<i>Liste du Steps</i><br /><table class='table table-condensed table-hover'>" +
            "<tbody><tr>" +
            "<th style='width: 10px'>#</th>" +
            "<th>Label</th>" +
            "<th>Type</th>" +
            "<th>Mode</th>" +
            "<th>Jump</th>" +
            "<th>Consequences</th>" +
            "</tr>" + row +
            "</tbody></table>";

    }
    $('#example1 tbody').on('click', '.addst-btn', function () {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        $scope.selectedrow = table.row(tr).data().code;
        console.log("ok");
        alert($scope.selectedrow);
        console.log($scope.selectedrow + " a ");

    });
    $('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        //console.log(this);
        //$(".details-control").not(this).click();
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/Spring4/data/steps?code=' + row.data().code
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                var tr1 = $(".shown");
                var row1 = table.row(tr1);
                row1.child.hide();
                tr1.removeClass('shown');
                row.child(format(response.data.ls)).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("error");
            });

        }
    });

    }

})();
```

THe problem is that the scope selectedrow is always not set when I click on #addst-btn but it works when I click on details-control

Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Addition,

I got it working when i added a $http request in the function strange isnt it ?

```
$('#example1 tbody').on('click', '.addst-btn', function () {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        $scope.selectedrow = table.row(tr).data().code;
        console.log("ok");
        alert($scope.selectedrow);
        console.log($scope.selectedrow + " a ");

    });
```

Comment: would be useful to see the html also. Could you create a codepen or similar?

Comment: also, you dont set the scope selected row in your second function

Comment: html is required too. better if you can create codepen or fiddle example link of your problem.

Comment: check the edit anyways its a datatable the html part is done by javascript

Comment: @hairmot i only set the scope in the first function but that wont work it only set when i press details-control

Comment: @SoltaniNeji I think the problem is with the [**DataTable.defaultContent**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent), you are using an `id='addst-btn'` which will be used for multiple elements, this is incorrect, `id`can only be unique, so change it with a class and change the js code accordingly.

Comment: @chsdk i remarqued that earlier but its always the same